# iOS Development, do we really need iPhone / iPod / iPad?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning

in order our apps to be submitted to apple store,
do we only need subscription to iOS developer program that cost $99,
or **we need iOS device such as iPhone or iPod touch too?**

I read from Book Phonegap Beginner Guide, we need to register
iOS device in order to get iOS provisioning profile.

I have mac mini with me, and I think i can afford to buy iOS Developer,
but is there any work around to get iOS provisioning profile without
buying iPhone or iPod?

Answer (score 1):

There is an simulator in the developer tools, you can use that. But still nothing beats the real thing though.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do your early stages of development without any hardware and only use the simulator.

But get an iPod Touch, at least. If you're going to spend your time on it, it better be worth the $300 for an iPod Touch.

Unlike Android, the iOS simulator is actually much faster than the actual device - and won't accurately reflect the performance on the device - let alone give you a sense of your app's actual usability. There are other intricacies you'll miss out on as well - like testing non-standard multi-touch gestures - or push notification testing - or gyro / compass / accelerometer / gps use. While some of those features can be simulated on the simulator - it's not the same as the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and submit apps with only the simulator, but it is doubtful if you can test it enough that way.

You need the provisioning profile to test on the devices, but if you do not have one, you would not need that, either.